# Listview - Multiple selection & Filterable

Tags: android, listview, search, filter

I am trying to develop `Listview` with multiple selection as well as filter text in a `Listview`.

below is my code,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add("abc " + i);
        }

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                //if (isOpened) {
                if (listadapter != null)
                    listadapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().trim());

                //}
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
```

### i have select item 1. and than after search some text , it shows me selected searched item.

### is there way to handle this

check images

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the images?

Comment: @Amit i am not expecting from you this kind of question . any way you can set this by using Adapter+ ListView . if you make a list with each item at different layout by set adapter then on item(position) you can filter items and you can select multiple items from that list.

Comment: i dont want in this way...after changing search i am getting checkbox selected for that search at that position.